# Create groups and take duration where the timelapse isnt greater than a specific number (R, Dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to create a 'group' and then takes its duration, given that the datetime sequence does not exceed 2 minutes.

```
DateA

5:00:01 PM
5:00:02 PM
5:00:03 PM
5:00:04 PM 
5:01:26 PM 
5:01:27 PM
5:01:28 PM 
5:01:30 PM
5:02:55 PM
5:02:56 PM
5:10:01 PM
```

This is the outcome I would like:

```
Group             Duration

  a                  3 sec 
  b                  4 sec
  c                  1 sec
  d                  0 sec
```

Where the datetime of 5:00:01, 5:00:02, 5:00:03 and 5:00:4 is grouped  as a
Where the datetime of 5:01:26, 5:01:27, 5:01:28, 5:01:30 is grouped as b
Where the datetime of 5:02:55, 5:02:56 is grouped as c
Where the datetime of 5:10:01 is grouped as d

```
Here is my dput:

structure(list(DateA = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("5:00:01", "5:00:02", "5:00:03", 
"5:00:04", "5:01:26", "5:01:27", "5:01:28", "5:01:30", "5:02:55", 
"5:02:56", "5:10:01"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

This is what I have tried, however, I am not certain how to modify the code to where the DateA column is grouped together with a thresh.

```
library(dplyr)
thresh <- 2

df %>%  
mutate(DateA = mdy_hms(DateA)) %>%
group_by(DateA, Group = cumsum(difftime(DateA, 
lag(DateA, default = first(DateA)), 
units = "mins") > thresh)) %>% summarise(Duration = 
difftime(max(DateAC), min(DateA), units = "secs")) %>%
ungroup %>%
mutate(Group = paste0('a', row_number()))
```

Comment: Is it 3 4, 1, 0 secs

Comment: `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, DateA := as.ITime(as.character(DateA))][,  .(Duration = difftime(last(as.POSIXct(DateA)), first(as.POSIXct(DateA)), unit = 'sec')),.(group = letters[cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DateA) > thresh))])]`

Comment: Yes sorry  I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `data.table` with `setDT`, change the 'DateA' to a Time object, create the 'group' by doing the cumulative sum of `diff` of logical expression and use `difftime` to calculate the difference in 'secs' between the `max` and `min`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, DateA := as.ITime(as.character(DateA))][, 
   .(Duration = difftime(max(as.POSIXct(DateA)), min(as.POSIXct(DateA)), 
     unit = 'sec')),.(group = letters[cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DateA) > thresh))])]
#   group Duration
#1:     a   3 secs
#2:     b   4 secs
#3:     c   1 secs
#4:     d   0 secs
```

---

Or we can change the grouping from `diff` to `difftime` to avoid any inconsistencies in `unit`s

```
setDT(df)[, DateA := as.ITime(as.character(DateA))][, 
         .(Duration = difftime(max(as.POSIXct(DateA)), min(as.POSIXct(DateA)), 
      unit = 'sec')), .(group = letters[cumsum(c(TRUE, 
      difftime(DateA[-1], DateA[-.N], unit = "min") > thresh))])]
```

Comment: @TanishaHudson yes, you can set it

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: Ok I set thresh <-1 and I am getting : 3,2,0,1,0   a,b,c,d,e respectively

Comment: @TanishaHudson  The new groups are created because of the difference in values

Comment: Ok, I am just trying to understand because I used the same dataset in my question. I figured I would get same output?

Comment: @TanishaHudson  No, you won't get the same output because the `cumsum` will add a new group whenever there is difference greater than 1 and in the case mentioned with thresh as 2.  it is greater than 2, iit adds a g roup

Comment: One more, isn’t the first group time difference 1 min and 22 secs? 5:00:04 to 5:01:26? So the 2 min thresh wouldn’t apply here right? (But it is breaking this into a group?) I am trying to fully understand

Comment: @TanishaHudson Just updating it

Comment: @TanishaHudson Are you compariing by seconds or minutes in thresh

Comment: Ok I am using minutes in thresh

Comment: @TanishaHudson ok, theen the updated `unit`s is in min

Comment: Hi @Akrun I am getting: Error in -.N : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Furthermore, when I use the code in my large dataset (5000 rows)  I get the output:    group a NA  Duration 0 NA  I am only getting an output of 2 rows, can you give some suggestion? Thank you

Comment: @TanishaHudson  May be you have some groups having just one row.  if that is the case, you can create a condition i.e. `if(.N > 1) do the difftime else just add a value` can you be able to subset the data and show a small reproudicble example so that I can  test it